# Prove $_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-27\right)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac47$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I discovered the following conjecture numerically, but have not been able to prove it yet:
$$_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-27\right)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac47.\tag1$$
The equality holds with at least $10000$ decimal digits of precision. It can be written in equivalent forms in terms of definite integrals:
$${\large\int}_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}\ \sqrt[3]{x^2+(3x)^3}}\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{\sqrt[3]4\,\sqrt3}{7\pi}\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right),\tag2$$
or
$${\large\int}_0^\pi\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt[3]{\sin\phi}\,\sqrt[3]{55+12\sqrt{21}\cos\phi}}\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{\sqrt[3]4\,\sqrt3}{7\pi}\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right).\tag3$$

---

*Update:* A several more equivalent forms:
$$_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac12;\frac56;\frac{27}{28}\right)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{2^{\small8/3}}{7^{\small2/3}}\tag4$$
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{55+\cosh x}}\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{\sqrt[3]2\,\sqrt3}{7\pi}\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right)\tag5$$
$$C_{\small-1/3}^{\small(1/3)}(55)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{3}{7\pi^2}\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right)\tag6$$
$$P_{\small-1/2}^{\small1/6}(55)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{\sqrt2\,\sqrt[4]3\,e^{\small-\pi\,i/12}}{7^{\small13/12}\,\pi^{\small3/2}}\Gamma^2\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right)\tag7$$
where $C_n^{(\lambda)}(x)$ is the [Gegenbauer polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html) and $P_l^m(x)$ is the [Legendre function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

---

- Please suggest ideas how to prove this conjecture.
- What are other points where the function $_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;z\right)$ takes simple special values?

Comment: The most obvious suggestion that comes to mind is some set of contiguous identities combined with a cubic transformation...but that's decidedly not the same as me seeing how to follow that path.

Comment: I suggest looking through the transformations in Section 15.3 of Abramowitz and Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions, to see if any of them transform your quantity into another ${}_2F_1$ value where a closed form is known (as in Section 15.1).

Comment: Another special value is apparently $_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-4\right)\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=3\cdot5^{-5/6}$.

Comment: By changing the argument from $-27$ to $5$, we get one of the roots of $~5^5x^6+12^3=0$.

Comment: Other special values are $x=-\dfrac13$ and $x=+\dfrac12$, for which the minimal polynomials are $9x^3-8$ and $16x^6-27$.

Comment: @Lucian _Mathematica_ seems to know about $-\frac13$ and $\frac12$, but not about $-4$ or $-27$.

Comment: +1, good question. Usually, without integer or half-integer arguments a,b,c in the 2F1s, I wouldn't even expect something like this. Of course you've checked Wolfram's functions site? They have a huge list of 2F1 identities.

Comment: @user_of_math I looked through the list, but did not check every formula.

Comment: I used $100-200$ decimals of precision, and a polynomial degree of $20$.

Comment: @Lucian: There may be infinitely many algebraic $z$ that qualifies. Kindly look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The conjecture is true, as are the other cases reported in the comments
where $f(z) := {}_2F_1 \left( \frac13, \frac13; \frac56; z \right)$
takes algebraic values for special rational values of $z$.
There are a few others obtained from the symmetry $z \leftrightarrow 1-z$
(these ${}_2F_1$ parameters correspond to a hyperbolic triangle group
with index $6,6,\infty$ at $c=0,1,\infty$, so the $z=0$ and $z=1$
indices coincide); e.g. $f(-1/3) = 2 / 3^{2/3}$ pairs with
$f(4/3) = 3^{-2/3} (5-\sqrt{-3})/2$.   ($z=1/2$ pairs with itself,
and the pair $f(-4)$ and $f(5)$ has been noted already;
the OP's $f(-27) = -4/7$ pairs with $f(28) = \frac12 - \frac3{14} \sqrt{-3}$.)
Somewhat more exotic are
$$
f\big({-}4\sqrt{13}\,(4+\sqrt{13})^3\big) = \frac7{13\,U_{13}}\\
f\big({-}\sqrt{11}\,(U_{33})^{3/2}\big) = \frac{6}{11^{11/12}\, U_{33}^{1/4}},
$$
with *[fundamental units](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html)* $U_{13}=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2,\;U_{33}=23+4\sqrt{33}$ and further values at algebraic conjugates and images under
$z \leftrightarrow 1-z$.

In general, for $z<1$ the integral formula for $f(z)$ relates it with
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{1-x} \; x^{2/3} (1-zx)^{1/3} }
$$
which is half of a "complete real period" for the holomorphic differential
$dx/y$ on the curve $C_z : y^6 = (1-x)^3 x^4 (1-zx)^2$.  This curve
has genus $2$, but is in the special family of genus-$2$ curves
with an automorphism of order $3$ (multiply $y$ by a cube root of unity),
for which both real periods are multiples of the real period of a
single elliptic curve $E_z$ (a.k.a. a complete elliptic integral).
In general the resulting formula doesn't simplify further, but when
$E_z$ has CM (complex multiplication) its periods can be expressed
in terms of gamma functions.  For $z = -27$ and the other special values
listed above, not only does $E_z$ have CM but the CM ring is contained in
${\bf Z}[\rho]$ where $\rho = e^{2\pi i/3} = (-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$.
Then the $\Gamma$ and $\pi$ factors of the period of $E_z$ exactly
match those in the integral formula, leaving us with
an algebraic value of $f(z)$.  It turns out that the choice $z = -27$
makes $E_z$ a curve with complex multiplication by ${\bf Z}[7\rho]$.
The others from the comments lead to ${\bf Z}[m\rho]$ with $m=1,2,3,5$,
and the examples where $z$ is a quadratic irrationality come from
${\bf Z}[13\rho]$ and ${\bf Z}[11\rho]$.

One way to get from $C_z$ to $E_z$ is to start from the change of variable
$u^3 = (1+cx)/x$, which gives
$$
f(z) = \int_{\root 3 \of {1-z}}^\infty \frac{3u \, du}{\sqrt{(u^3+z)(u^3+z-1)}}.
$$
and identifies $C_z$ with the hyperelliptic curve $v^2 = (u^3+z)(u^3+z-1)$.
Now in general a curve $v^2 = u^6+Au^3+B^6$ has an involution $\iota$ taking
$u$ to $B^2/u$, and the quotient by $\iota$ is an elliptic curve;
we compute that this curve has $j$-invariant
$$
j = 6912 \frac{(5+2r)^3}{(2-r)^3(2+r)}
$$
where $A = rB^3$.  (There are two choices of $\iota$, related by
$v \leftrightarrow -v$, and thus two choices of $j$, related by
$r \leftrightarrow -r$; but the corresponding elliptic curves
are $3$-isogenous, so their periods are proportional.)
In our case $r = A/B^3 = -(2z+1)/\sqrt{z^2+z}$ (in which the
$z \leftrightarrow 1-z$ symmetry takes $r$ to $-r$).  Taking $z=-27$
yields $j = -2^{15} 3^4 5^3 (52518123 \pm 11460394\sqrt{21})$,
which are the $j$-invariants of the ${\bf Z}[7\rho]$ curves;
working backwards from the $j$-invariants of the other
${\bf Z}[m\rho]$ curves we find the additional values of $z$
noted in the comments and earlier in this answer.

Comment: I like this approach very much, despite only understanding this algebraic curves machinery just enough to mostly follow it. I'm a bit puzzled, though: Your answer makes clear that the $z=-27$ _should_ be algebraic, but I don't see where the fact of it being $4/7$ in particular is shown.

Comment: Good question.  Basically you follow the differential 
$dx / (\sqrt{1-x} \; x^{2/3} (1-zx)^{1/3})$ through the
changes of variable corresponding to the maps from $C_z$ to 
$E_z = C_z/\iota$ and the 3-isogenous curve $C_z/-\iota$,
and then use the $m$-isogeny from the ${\bf Z}[m\rho]$ curve
to a ${\bf Z}[\rho]$ curve to relate the period to the
Beta integral $\int_0^1 dt/(t-t^2)^{1/3}$ which cancels the
transcendental factor $\Gamma^3(1/3)/\pi$.  Once $m$ gets as large as
$5$ or $7$, let alone $11$ or $13$, the actual formula for the
$m$-isogeny can get complicated, but we know how to find it.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I know this is an old answer, but how do you know which values of $j$ to look for?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Made some minor changes for aesthetics. I hope it's ok.

Comment: Not sure what you changed and why . . .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Can you kindly look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2)? I may have found a way to find infinitely many $z$ using the classical j-function.

Comment: @Kirill: Like you, I wondered about that as well. [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2) may answer that question.

Answer (score 9):

(This is more a comment than answer, but I couldn't get MathJax to properly show it in comments)

Here is a nice identity (equation (21) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408269.pdf) with $x=-1/7$): $$_2F_1 \left(a,a+\frac{1}{2};\frac{4a+5}{6};-\frac{1}{7}\right)=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^a {_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{3},\frac{a+1}{3};\frac{4a+5}{6};-27\right)$$

It's an example of a cubic transformation. *Possibly*, one can at this point use contiguous relations to make some progress.

Comment: Note that the obvious choice of $a=0$ is useless since both sides equal one in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your secondary question, by appealing to the classical *j-function* at defined arguments, it seems there are infinitely many algebraic numbers $z$ such that the $_2F_1$ evaluates to an algebraic number. Some examples,
$$_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-z_1\right)= \frac9{17} \big(833+324\cdot17^{1/3}-252\cdot17^{2/3}\big)^{1/6}$$
$$2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-z_2\right)= \frac{10}{3\cdot19} \big(2+2\cdot19^{1/3}-19^{2/3}\big)$$
where,
$$z_1 =4\big(19894+7737\cdot17^{1/3}+3009\cdot17^{2/3}\big)$$
$$z_2 =\frac{1}{3}\big(1464289+548752\cdot19^{1/3}+205648\cdot19^{2/3}\big)$$
See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2).