# Prove ${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5\,x}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{2/3}}=\frac{3^{3/2}}{2^{4/3}5^{5/6}\pi }\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Here is one more conjecture I discovered numerically:
$${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5\,x}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}}\stackrel{\color{#808080}?}=\frac{3^{\small3/2}}{2^{\small4/3}\,5^{\small5/6}\,\pi }\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right)$$
How can we prove it?

Note that $\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5}=\phi^2$.
*Mathematica* can evaluate this integral, but gives a large expression in terms of Gauss and Appel hypergeometric functions of irrational arguments.

Comment: It's quite 'natural' that powers of three monomial [yields a Hypergeometric Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).

Comment: The 'trick' will be to go from the Hyper$\ldots$ to your guess$\ldots$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask directly for a general approach to evaluating $\displaystyle\int_{0\text{ or }-1}^1(x^n+a)^m(1-x^p)^q~dx$. For $a=0$, the connection to the beta function is obvious.

Comment: Perhaps the formula $\int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} (p + x)^{-a - b} \,dx= \frac{ B(a, b) }{ p^b (1+p)^a }$ can be of use here. I made an attempt but with no success so far.

Comment: The integral clearly gives a hypergeometric function (set $x=2t-1$). The equivalent identity is $$_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;\frac23; -40\eta^3\right)= \frac{3}{5\eta},$$ where $\eta=5^{-1/6}\phi^2$.

Comment: Using DLMF15.8.13 and 15.8.15, we have another equivalent identity:
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac13;\frac12;\frac56;\frac45\right)\stackrel?=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$

Comment: Have you tried putting it up for a bounty ?

Comment: Look like it's partially solved by the top answer in [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879089/prove-2f-1-left-frac13-frac13-frac56-27-right-stackrel-color808080?rq=1).

Comment: @Vladimir: There seems to be an explanation for the presence of $9+4\sqrt{5} =\phi^6$ in the integral. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043030/closed-forms-for-int-0-infty-fracdx-sqrt355-cosh-x-and-int-0-inf) for cube roots and [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044362/on-big-tfrac1-sqrt52-big12-small-16172-sqrt5-and-int-11) for fourth roots.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will start with and prove Chen Wang's equivalent formulation:
$$ F\left({\tfrac13,\tfrac12\atop \tfrac56}\middle| \tfrac45 \right) =
\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}. $$

By the integral representation of hypergeometric functions
 ([DLMF 15.6.E1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1)), this is equal to
$$ \frac1{B(\frac13,\frac12)}\int_0^1
\frac{dx}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{1/2}(1-A^6x)^{1/2}}, $$
where $A = (4/5)^{1/6}$ is easier to use than $\frac45$. Let the
integral be denoted by $I$. Introducing two changes of variables,
$x\mapsto 1/u^3$ and later $u=A^2/v$, we see that
$$ I = \int_1^\infty \frac{3u du}{\sqrt{(u^3-1)(u^3-A^6)}} =
\int_0^{A^2} \frac{3A\,dv}{\sqrt{(1-v^3)(A^6-v^3)}}. $$

The hyperelliptic curve
$$ y^2 = (x^3-1)(x^3-A^6), \qquad \frac{1}{3A}I = \int_0^{A^2}\frac{dx}{y} =
\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{A}\frac{dx}{y} $$
admits an involution $x\mapsto A^2/x$, and, as demonstrated very
clearly by Jyrki Lahtonen
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969339), there is a
rational change of variables that maps this curve onto the curve
$$ s^2 = t^3 + 9A^2t^2 + 6A(A^3+1)^2t+(A^3+1)^4. $$

In particular, first by writing
$$ u = x+A^2/x, \qquad v = y\left(\frac1x + \frac A{x^2}\right),
\qquad \frac{v/y}{du/dx} = \frac1{x-A}, $$
we get
$$ \frac{2}{3A} I = \int_0^{A^2}\frac{dx}{y} + \int_1^\infty
\frac{x}{A}\frac{dx}{y} = \int_{1+A^2}^\infty
\frac{du}{v}\frac{v/y}{du/dx}\left(\frac xA-1\right) = \frac{{\color{red}6}}{A}\int_{1+A^2}^\infty \frac{du}{v}. $$
(I lost a factor of $6$ somewhere in my notes; I'll edit this once I
find it.) And transforming to
$$ t = -\frac{(A^3+1)^2}{u+2A}, \qquad s =
\frac{(A^3+1)^2v}{(u+2A)^2}, $$
gives
$$ I = 9\int_{t_1}^{0}\frac{dt}{s}, \qquad t_1 = -(1-A+A^2)^2. $$

Finally, the curve $(s,t)$ is elliptic, and `sage`'s function
 `isogenies_prime_degree` tells us that there exists a rational map
 given by
$$\begin{eqnarray}z &=& \Big(9000 A^2 \left(754+843 A^3\right) t+63000 \left(94+105 A^3\right) t^2+67500 A \left(34+35 A^3\right) t^3\\&&+112500 A^2 \left(4+3 A^3\right) t^4+45000 t^5\Big)\Big/\\&&\Big(60508 A^2+67650 A^5+100 \left(754+843 A^3\right) t+75 A \left(514+575 A^3\right) t^2\\&&+625 A^2\left(14+15 A^3\right) t^3+1250 t^4\Big),\end{eqnarray}$$
$$ w/s = \left(345600 \left(51841+57960 A^3\right)+7776000 A \left(2889+3230 A^3\right) t+1620000 A^2 \left(8278+9255 A^3\right) t^2+1080000 \left(4136+4635 A^3\right) t^3+48600000 A \left(21+25 A^3\right) t^4+10125000 A^2 \left(14+15 A^3\right) t^5+13500000 t^6\right)/\left(32 \left(832040+930249 A^3\right)+1200 A \left(46368+51841 A^3\right) t+300 A^2 \left(159454+178275 A^3\right) t^2+5000 \left(3872+4329 A^3\right) t^3+7500 A \left(648+725 A^3\right) t^4+46875 A^2 \left(14+15 A^3\right) t^5+62500 t^6\right) $$
with
$$ \frac{w/s}{dz/dt} = 6, $$
that maps the curve $(s,t)$ to the curve
$$ w^2 = z^3+180^3. $$

This means that the integral is given by
$$ I = 9\times 6\times \int_{-180}^0 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^3+180^3}} =
\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}B(\tfrac12,\tfrac13), $$
where the last integral is elementary in terms of beta functions. Putting things together gives
the desired result.

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by **Chen Wang**, this integral is related to an integral of the form
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{1-x} \; x^{2/3} (1-zx)^{1/3} }
$$
which appears in this forum's
[Question 879089](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879089)
by the same author.

Here's a more direct route than given by **Kirill**, without
conversions between definite integrals and hypergeometric functions.
A differential $dx \left/ \left(\sqrt[3]{A+Bx} \, (1-x^2)^{2/3}\right)\right.$
has four poles of fractional order, two at $x = \pm 1$ of order $2/3$,
and two at $x = \infty$ and $x = -B/A$ of order $1/3$.
Hence the differential is invariant under an involution
in the form of a fractional linear transformation that switches
$-1 \leftrightarrow +1$ and $\infty \leftrightarrow -B/A$.
To exploit this symmetry it is convenient to use a coordinate
$u = (cx+1)/(x+c)$: for any $c$ we have $u=\pm 1$ at $x = \pm 1$
and $u = c$ at $x = \infty$, and we choose $c>1$ so that $u=-c$ at $x=-B/A$.
Explicitly, this change of variable gives
$$
{\large\int}_{-1}^1
  \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{c^2+1+2cx}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}}
=
{\large\int}_{-1}^1
  \frac{du}{\sqrt[3]{c^2-u^2}\ \left(1-u^2\right)^{\small2/3}} .
$$
By symmetry the second $\int_{-1}^1$ is $2\int_0^1$ of the same integrand,
and then the change of variable $u^2 = t$ gives
$$
{\large\int}_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t} \, (c^2-t)^{\small1/3} (1-t)^{\small2/3}}.
$$
Now integrating with respect to $X=1-t$ instead of $t$ gives
$$
{\large\int}_0^1 \frac{dX}{\sqrt{1-X} \; X^{2/3}
  \left(c^2-1+X\right)^{\small1/3}},
$$
and we have reached an integral of the desired form.

In the present case we take $c = \frac12 \! \sqrt 5$.
Then $c^2+1 + 2cx = (9 + 4\sqrt{5}x)/4$, so our integral is
$4^{1/3}$ times the one with $\sqrt[3]{9 + 4\sqrt{5}x}$ in the denominator.
Hence $c^2-1 = 1/4$, so we gain another factor of $4^{1/3}$ and we've reached 
the integral in the first display with $z=-4$.  **Vladimir Reshetnikov**
already noted in a comment to his question that the integral seemed to
have an exact value at $z = -4$, and the analysis I gave in my answer there
(or **Kirill**'s answer here) leads to the period of a CM elliptic curve
with $j$-invariant $146329141248 \sqrt{5} - 327201914880$; this curve is
related by $5$-isogeny with a curve of $j$-invariant zero, and thus
has a period proportional to a Beta integral.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a generalization of your conjecture:

> If $k>0$ real number, then
>
> $${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{k\pm\tfrac{4\sqrt5k}{9}\,x}\
>  \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}}\stackrel{?}{=}
>  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}\cdot\frac{3^{\small13/6}}{2^{\small4/3}5^{\small5/6}\pi}\Gamma^{3}\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right).$$

For $k=9$ with $+$ sign it gives back your integral.

Another family of this type:

> If $k>0$ real number, then
>
> $${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{k\pm\tfrac{4k}{5}\,x}\
>  \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}}\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{3}\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right).
> $$