# Prove ${_2F_1}\left({{\tfrac16,\tfrac23}\atop{\tfrac56}}\middle|\,\frac{80}{81}\right)=\frac 35 \cdot 5^{1/6} \cdot 3^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I've found the following [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) value by numerical observation. The identity matches at least for $100$ digits.

$${_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac16,\tfrac23\\\tfrac56\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{80}{81}\right) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac 35 \cdot 5^{1/6} \cdot 3^{2/3}$$

Or using a [Pfaff transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_24_solutions) in an equivalent form

$$81^{1/6} \cdot {_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac16,\tfrac16\\\tfrac56\end{array}\middle|\,-80\right) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac 35 \cdot 5^{1/6} \cdot 3^{2/3}$$

How could we prove it?

---

Other related problem: How could we prove that

$${_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac16,\tfrac23\\\tfrac56\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{80}{81}\right) \stackrel{?}{=} {_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,\tfrac56\\\tfrac12\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{4}{9}\right) = {_1F_0}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac56\\\ - \,\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{4}{9}\right)$$

Comment: Is there a reason you are interested in this particular hypergeometric series? If you give some background, you will likely attract more attention to this problem. By the way, it's Pfaff, with an f.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879854).

Comment: @Lucian Yes, the inspiration of the problem was Vladimir's question. This is an equivalent problem.

Comment: @Daniel While I tried to solve Vladimir's question what Lucian linked as a related problem, I have stucked at this point.

Comment: Maybe your problem can be answered using the technique in this paper: [Transformations of Algebraic Gauss Hypergeometric Functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4808v1) by Raimundas Vidunas

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Thank you for your comment, but I've already read this paper, and I didn't find an answer there. By the way this question has been answered, since the problem is equivalent to Vladimirs problem linked above by Lucian. Because there is a solution there, if you want to take the bounty, you could find how to transform the integralproblem there a problem where appears this hypergeometric series. I can give you the result, but only by using CAS.

Comment: @user153012 I tried to answer this OP, but it's really hard. I tried to find the correspondence formula in Gradshteyn & Rhyzhik but I've not found it yet

Comment: There seem to be a number of hypergeometric identities that take $z \rightarrow 4z(1-z)$ in the argument. This transform takes $4/9 \rightarrow 80/81$, so it's likely that the identity in question has this argument transformation (though none of the ones I could find fit this particular case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879854/153012) by Vladimir. Because it is [already proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/970918/153012) that
$${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5\,x}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}} = \frac{3^{\small3/2}}{2^{\small4/3}\,5^{\small5/6}\,\pi }\Gamma^3\!\!\left(\tfrac13\right),$$

we have the answer for my question too, since according to *Maple*

$${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5\,x}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3}} = \frac{2}{9} \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}\,\sqrt[3]{3}\,\pi^2\,{_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac16,\tfrac23\\\tfrac56\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{80}{81}\right)}{\Gamma^3 \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)}.$$

The second part of the question $-$ the part under the line $-$ is still open.

Comment: Instead of finding the closed form of the hypergeometric function, why wouldn't we transform the hypergeometric function in RHS to LHS? All we need is some clever substitutions. +1 ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Answer (score 3):

(*This may not be complete, but generalizes the observation for context*.) The OP's answer mentioned Reshetnikov's integral which can be expressed as,
$$\frac{1}{48^{1/4}\,K(k_3)}\,\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt{5}\,x}\,\left(1-x^2\right)^{\small2/3} } =\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3};\tfrac{5}{6};-4\big)= \frac{3}{5^{5/6}} $$
so it will be fruitful to find a transformation between Reshetnikov's use of $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3};\tfrac{5}{6};z_1\big)$ and the OP's use of $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{6},\tfrac{2}{3};\tfrac{5}{6};z_2\big)$. Employing well-known transformations, we get,

> $$G(y)=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{3}, \tfrac{1}{3};\tfrac{5}{6}; -y\big) = \big(\tfrac1{1+2y}\big)^{1/3}\,_2F_1\Big(\tfrac{1}{6}, \tfrac{2}{3};\tfrac{5}{6}; \tfrac{(1+2y)^2-1}{(1+2y)^2}\Big)$$

It is [conjectured](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2) that if $y$ are certain algebraic numbers, than $G(y)$ is also an algebraic number. Specializing the RHS, define as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069657/),

$$H(\tau)=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac23;\tfrac56;(1-2\delta_4)^2\big),\quad\text{where}\;\frac1{\delta_4}-1=\frac1{27}\left(\tfrac{\eta\big((\tau+1)/3\big)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{12}$$
with *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$. If $\tau = \frac{1+N\sqrt{-3}}2$ for some integer $N>1$, then the conjecture implies both $\delta_4$ and $H(\delta_4)$ are algebraic numbers. For example, if we use $\tau = \frac{1+5\sqrt{-3}}2$ and $\tau = \frac{1+7\sqrt{-3}}2$, respectively, then we recover your,
$$H\big(\tfrac{1+\color{blue}5\sqrt{-3}}2\big)=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac23;\tfrac56;\tfrac{80}{81}\big) = \tfrac3{\color{blue}5}\,(9\sqrt5)^{1/3}$$
as well as,
$$H\big(\tfrac{1+\color{blue}7\sqrt{-3}}2\big)=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac23;\tfrac56;\tfrac{3024}{3025}\big) = \tfrac4{\color{blue}7}\,55^{1/3}$$
and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The Tito Piezas answer is related to this parameterization for
${}_2F_1(\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{6};z)$ in terms of modular forms:
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{6};
\frac{j_{3A}}{j_{3A}-108}\right)
= \eta(\tau)\; \eta(3\tau)\;(j_{3A}-108)^{1/6}\;
\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3
\frac{(-6i\tau+\sqrt{3}-3i)}{2^{7/3}\pi}
\tag{1}$$
where $\eta$ is the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) and [$j_{3A}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series#Level_3) is
$$
j_{3A} = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)^6}{\eta(3\tau)^6}+
\frac{3^3 \eta(3\tau)^6}{\eta(\tau)^6}\right)^2
$$
(Choosing the proper branches of the sixth root and the ${}_2F_1$).

Take $\tau = \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{5}{6}\sqrt{3}$ to get the required result from special values of $\eta$...

$$
\eta\left(\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{5}{6}\sqrt{3}\right)
=2^{-3/2} 3^{3/8} 5^{-5/12} (1+\sqrt5)^{1/2} \pi^{-1}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3/2} (-1)^{1/24}
$$
and something similar for $\eta(3\tau)$, so
$$
j_{3A}(\tau) = -8640,\qquad
\frac{j_{3A}(\tau)}{j_{3A}(\tau)-108} = \frac{80}{81}
$$
In $(1)$, the product of $\Gamma(1/3)$ and $\Gamma(2/3)$ simplify to something algebraic together with a $\pi$, and the powers of $\pi$ cancel.