# Interesting closed form for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{3}+\sin^2{\theta}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\;d\theta$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form, gamma-function, elliptic-integrals

Some time ago I used a formal approach to derive the following identity:

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{3}+\sin^2{\theta}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\;d\theta=\frac{3^{\frac{1}{12}}\pi\sqrt{2}}{AGM(1+\sqrt{3},\sqrt{8})}\tag{1}$$

where $AGM$ is the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) does not tell me whether this is correct, but it does appear to be accurate to many decimal places. I have three questions:

1. Can anyone verify whether $(1)$ is in fact correct?
2. Is there a way of generalizing $(1)$ to integrals of the form $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(a+\sin^2{\theta}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\;d\theta$ or is this integral more special? My derivation (see below) appears to only work for $a=\frac{1}{3}$.
3. There is a superficial similarity between $(1)$ and [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) (e.g. the [$AGM$ evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean#Properties)); is there a way to transform this integral into an elliptic integral that I have missed, or is it merely a [coincidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence) that an integral of this form is the [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of an $AGM$?

---

**Derivation**: I have put this here in case it helps to see where I am coming from; I apologize for its length. I began by using a [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral) integration [trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates) of squaring the integral and converting to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#From_polar_coordinates) to evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^6}dx=\frac{1}{6}\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})$ as follows:

$$\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-x^6}\;dx\right]^2=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}re^{-r^6(\cos^6\theta\;+\;\sin^6\theta)}\;d\theta\;dx={\int_0^\infty re^{-r^6}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{3r^6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}\;d\theta\;dx}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty re^{-r^6}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\frac{3r^6}{4}\sin^22\theta}\;d\theta\;dx={\int_0^\infty re^{-r^6}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\frac{3r^6}{4}\cos^2\theta}\;d\theta\;dx}$$

I then made use of the following formula (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038286/accurate-identities-related-to-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac2nn3x)):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}x^n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{4x\cos^2\theta}\;d\theta\tag{2}$$

Using $(2)$ and formally interchanging integration and summation we get:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})^2}{36}=\int_0^\infty re^{-r^6}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{4\left(\frac{3r^6}{16}\right)\cos^2\theta}\;d\theta\;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty re^{-r^6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}\left(\frac{3r^6}{16}\right)^n\;dx$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^n \int_0^\infty r^{6n+1}e^{-r^6}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{12}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^n \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

I then used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) and $(2)$, freely interchanging integrals and sums, to write:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{s^{n+\frac{1}{3}}}=L\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}t^{n-\frac{2}{3}}\right](s)={\frac{2}{\pi}L\left[t^{-\frac{2}{3}}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{4t\cos^2\theta}\;d\theta\right](s)}={\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}L\left[t^{-\frac{2}{3}}e^{4t\cos^2\theta}\right](s)\;d\theta}={\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})}{(s-4\cos^2\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\;d\theta}$$

Accordingly, since $\frac{4}{3}-\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{3}+\sin^2{\theta}$ we can deduce that:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})^2}{36}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})}{6}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{3}+\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\;d\theta$$

[Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formula) and [duplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html) give $\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})=2^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})^2$ and hence we have the following identity:

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{3}+\sin^2{\theta}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\;d\theta=\frac{3^\frac{1}{3}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})^3}{2^\frac{7}{3}\pi}\tag{3}$$

while $(1)$ may be obtained by using the following [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1631760/284973)):

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\frac{2^\frac{14}{9}3^\frac{1}{3}\pi^\frac{5}{6}}{AGM(1+\sqrt{3},\sqrt{8})^\frac{2}{3}}$$

This completes the derivation; I cannot see how a method like this (especially with the conversion to polar coordinates) could be used to give results more general than $(1)$ and $(3)$.

Comment: Testing your result numerically in Maple, it's correct to 100 decimal places.

Comment: A partial result: your integral is equivalent to $$3\sqrt[3]\frac34\int_{\sqrt[3]\frac43}^{\infty }\frac{\mathrm d w}{\sqrt[3]{w^3-1} \sqrt{3 w^3-4}}$$

Comment: My original approach was to express $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}$ as a value of the Beta function and as an elliptic integral of the first kind, too. That gives $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$ can be computed through the AGM, and by exploiting the properties of the AGM and Legendre's duplication formula we get the wanted result.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}}=\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(a,b)}.$$

Comment: It and others can be expressed as,$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\tfrac13+\sin^2 x}}dx=3^{1/12}\,K(k_3)$$ $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{4+\sin^2 x}}dx=\frac{3^{3/4}}{5^{5/6}}\,K(k_3)$$ $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{27+\sin^2 x}}dx=\frac{3^{3/4}}7\,K(k_3)$$ with [elliptic integral singular value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) $\displaystyle K(k_3) = \frac{3^{1/4}\,\Gamma^3\big(\tfrac13\big)}{2^{7/3}\,\pi}$. See answer below.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician: It turns out this integral is connected to [another integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2107512/4781) I asked about before.

Answer (score 7):

Making the substitution $\displaystyle \,\, \cos x = \operatorname{sech} t,$ the integral is transformed into
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{4}{3}-\cos^2 x\right)^{-1/3} \, dx
 = \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{4}{3}-\operatorname{sech}^2 t\right)^{-1/3} \, \operatorname{sech} t \, dt.$$
Now, using the triple-angle formula $\displaystyle \, \, \cosh(3 z) =4 \, \cosh^3 z -3 \, \cosh z,$ we can simplify it to
$$I= \int_0^\infty  \left( \dfrac{\cosh(3 t)}{3 \, \cosh^3 t} \right)^{-1/3} \, \operatorname{sech} t \, dt
\\\\= 3^{1/3} \int_0^{\infty} (\operatorname{sech} 3 t)^{1/3} \, dt.$$

See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379526/219995) how we can easily show that 
$$\int_0^{\infty} (\operatorname{sech} t)^{s} dt = \frac12 B\left(\frac{s}{2},\frac12\right).$$

This gives your integral as 
$$ I = 3^{-2/3} \cdot  \frac12 B\left(\frac16,\frac12\right)$$

which you can bring to your equivalent representation using the functional equations of the Gamma function.

Comment: @Nemo I understood his questions as seeking both a generalization, and a verifciation of this specific case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer +1. I am interested to see that the integral can be converted to a similar representation to that which Jack D'Aurizio used to derive the $\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})$ identity I quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

*This is answer to question 3.*

Expanding into the powers of $\frac{\cos^2x}{s+4}$ and integrating termwise one obtains
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{s+4 \sin ^2x}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{s+4 -4\cos ^2x}}dx=\frac{\pi  \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};1;\frac{4}{s+4}\right)}{2 \sqrt[3]{s+4}}.
$$
Use Pfaff's transformation to write
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};1;\frac{4}{s+4}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{s+4}{s}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};1;-\frac{4}{s}\right).
$$
By transformation 2.11(5) from Erdelyi, Higher transcendental functions
$$
_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};1;-\frac{4}{s}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{s}+1}+1}\right)^{4/3} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{s}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{s}}+1}\right)^2\right)
$$
Now apply Pfaff's transformation
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;\left(\tfrac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{s}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{s}}+1}\right)^2\right)=\left(\tfrac{4 \sqrt{\frac{4}{s}+1}}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{s}+1}+1\right)^2}\right)^{-2/3} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;-\tfrac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{s+4}{s}}-1\right)^2}{4 \sqrt{\frac{s+4}{s}}}\right)
$$
It is known that this last hypergeometric function is elliptic integral. Introduce the following parametrization from Ramanujan's Notebooks, PART V, formula 5.17
$$
s=-2+\frac{2i}{3 \sqrt{3}}\frac{\left(2+2p-p^2\right) \left(1+4p+p^2\right) \left(1-2p-2 p^2\right)}{p \left(1-p^2\right) (p+2) (2 p+1)},\tag{1}
$$
then
$$
\sqrt{2 p+1} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;-\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{s+4}{s}}-1\right)^2}{4 \sqrt{\frac{s+4}{s}}}\right)=\left(p^2+p+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{p^3 (p+2)}{2 p+1}\right),
$$
and after combining all the formulas

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{s+4 \sin ^2x}}dx=\frac{\pi  \left(p^2+p+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{p^3 (p+2)}{2 p+1}\right)}{2\sqrt{2 p+1}  \sqrt[6]{s (s+4)}}
> $$
>   with parametrization (1).

As an example $p=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{3}{2^{2/3}}+\frac{i}{2} \sqrt{3 \left(13-4 \sqrt[3]{2}-5\cdot 2^{2/3}\right)}$, then $s=\frac43$ and
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac13+\sin ^2x}}dx=\frac{3^{1/3} \pi \left(p^2+p+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{p^3 (p+2)}{2 p+1}\right)}{2^{4/3}\sqrt{2 p+1} }
$$

A more convenient parametrization in terms of eta-quotients can be obtained similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2061175/285751):

> Define $\tau=\frac{1+n\sqrt{-3}}{2}$,$~w=-\frac{1}{\tau+1}$,$~\alpha=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{27}}\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}} \sqrt{27} \left(\frac{\eta (3 w)}{\eta (w)}\right)^3-e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4} }\left(\frac{\eta (3 w)}{\eta (w)}\right)^{-3}\right)^2$, and $~r=\alpha(\alpha+1),$ then
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\alpha+\sin ^2x}}dx 
> &=-\frac{\pi w\sqrt{3} ~i }{2\sqrt[6]{r}}\left(\frac{\eta (2 w) \eta^6 (3 w)}{\eta^2 (w) \eta^3 (6 w)}+4\frac{\eta (w)\eta^6 (6 w) }{\eta^2 (2 w) \eta^3 (3 w)}\right)\\[2.5mm]
> &=-\frac{\pi w\sqrt{3} ~i }{2\sqrt[6]{r}}\left(\frac{\big(\vartheta_4(0,q^6)\big)^3}{\vartheta_4(0,q^2)}+\frac{\big(\vartheta_2(0,q^3)\big)^3}{\vartheta_2(0,q)}\right)\\[2.5mm]
> &=-\frac{\pi w\sqrt{3} ~i }{2\sqrt[6]{r}}\;_2F_1\large\left(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;1;\tfrac{2r\,+\,(1+2\alpha)\sqrt{r}}{4r}\right)\end{aligned}
> $$
>   with *Jacobi theta functions* $\vartheta_n(0,q)$ and *nome* $q=e^{\pi i\, w}$.

For example $n=3$ gives $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: The ratio of the integral of this post and the other post, if $\alpha$ is used, turns out to be a simple algebraic form dependent on $\tau$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII , yes, it is no surprize because both are proportional to the same elliptic integral $K\Big(\sqrt{\tfrac{p^3 (2+p)}{1+2 p}}\Big)$.

Comment: For the conclusion, I added some equivalent forms as Jacobi thetas and $_2F_1$. I hope it's ok. By the way, I like how the form $r=\alpha(1+\alpha)$ always turns up.

Comment: Many thanks for this awesome answer to my third question; the elliptic integral transformation certainly doesn't seem simple. I'm not sure which answer to mark correct since my questions have been answered in different answers. I'm certainly very grateful for the work that's gone into the answers.

Answer (score 6):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

Expanding on a concluding remark by Nemo, there is an interesting connection between the OP's,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\color{blue}{\alpha}+\sin^2 x}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\,\sqrt[3]{\alpha+1}}\,_2F_1\Big(\frac12,\frac13;1;\,\frac1{\color{blue}{\alpha}+1}\Big)\tag1$$
and the integral involved in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2),
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\color{blue}{1+2\alpha}+\cosh x}}dx=2^{2/3}\,3^{1/4}K(k_3)\;_2F_1\Big(\frac13,\frac13;\frac56;-\color{blue}{\alpha}\Big)\tag2$$
Equations $(1),(2)$ are valid for *arbitrary* $\alpha$. But if it is chosen such that,
$$\color{blue}{\alpha} =\alpha(\tau)= \frac1{4\sqrt{27}}\big(\lambda^3-\sqrt{27}\lambda^{-3}\big)^2$$
where,
$$\lambda =\frac{\eta\big(\frac{\tau+1}3\big)}{\eta(\tau)},\quad \tau=\frac{1+N\sqrt{-3}}2$$
then there is a beautifully **simple** relationship between $(1),(2)$ as,

> $$\frac{N+1}{2^{1/3}\,3^{1/2}}\,\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\color{blue}{\alpha}+\sin^2 x}}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\color{blue}{1+2\alpha}+\cosh x}}dx\tag3$$

The closed-form for the RHS (via its hypergeometric equivalent) is already given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066155/4781), so that automatically leads to the form for the LHS as well. Some rational values are,

$$\alpha\big(\tfrac{1+3\sqrt{-3}}2\big)=\large\tfrac13$$
$$\alpha\big(\tfrac{1+5\sqrt{-3}}2\big)=4$$
$$\alpha\big(\tfrac{1+7\sqrt{-3}}2\big)=27$$

which will be algebraic for integer $N>1$. The first one was re-discovered by the OP and lead to the nice evaluations,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\tfrac13+\sin^2 x}}dx=3^{1/12}\,K(k_3)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{4+\sin^2 x}}dx=\frac{3^{3/4}}{5^{5/6}}\,K(k_3)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{27+\sin^2 x}}dx=\frac{3^{3/4}}7\,K(k_3)$$

Comment: +1. Thank you for this nice answer. This was the sort of nice connection to existing theory I was looking for. It seems $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$ is not alone in having a nice answer of this form. I'll take a while to go through everything here!

Comment: This is a really good answer. I had no idea what I was getting into when I posted my question (I hadn't studied the hypergeometric function much) but there is some very beautiful theory here and in the linked post.