# How to show ${_2F_1}\left(-\frac{19}{20}, \frac{11}{30}; -\frac{19}{30}; -2\right)$ is zero.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, hypergeometric-function

I have seen hypergeometric functions over the years on Wolfram Alpha and am trying to learn more about them. I recently read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879089/prove-2f-1-left-frac13-frac13-frac56-27-right-stackrel-color808080) and its associated answers, but understood very little. I wrote a program to arbitrarily search for interesting hypergeometric function values and stumbled on this one.

How do I prove the following identity?

$$ {_2F_1}\left(-\frac{19}{20}, \frac{11}{30}; -\frac{19}{30}; -2\right) = 0 $$

This *would be* equivalent to the following sum, where $(x)_n$ refer to the rising factorial or Pochhammer symbol. However, $\left|- 2\right|$ is not less than $1$, so this sum is not guaranteed to converge.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{19}{20}\right)_n \cdot \left(\frac{11}{30}\right)_n}{\left(-\frac{19}{30}\right)_n\cdot(1)_n} \cdot (-2)^n $$

I tried applying the first Pfaff transformation in order to get $-2$ back in the radius of convergence:

$$ {_2 F_1}(a, b; c; x) \Longrightarrow (1-z)^{-b}\cdot{_2 F_1}\left(b,c-a;c;\frac{z}{z-1}\right) $$

$$ {_2F_1}\left(-\frac{19}{20}, \frac{11}{30}; -\frac{19}{30}; -2\right) \Longrightarrow 3^{-\frac{11}{30}} \cdot {_2F_1} \left( \frac{11}{30}, \frac{19}{60}; -\frac{19}{30}; \frac{2}{3} \right) $$

Because the sum converges to zero, I can ignore the leading $3^{-\frac{11}{30}}$ .

The trick worked and it gave me something I can sum numerically.

Here is a table with the first 10 terms of the transformed hypergeometric series (without the leading constant).

```
0 1.0
1 -0.12222222222222222
2 -0.19993827160493827
3 -0.1782466849565615
4 -0.14016354150790022
5 -0.1046338569817722
6 -0.07596678344256204
7 -0.05421630175119416
8 -0.03824906471494405
9 -0.026761952441104003
```

And here are the first twenty partial sums

```
0 0.0
1 1.0
2 0.8777777777777778
3 0.6778395061728395
4 0.499592821216278
5 0.3594292797083778
6 0.2547954227266056
7 0.17882863928404355
8 0.1246123375328494
9 0.08636327281790535
10 0.05960132037680134
11 0.040992463681377815
12 0.028115033171369225
13 0.01923797177189061
14 0.01313772602200051
15 0.008956592581665427
16 0.006097117468555947
17 0.004145193056747411
18 0.00281493829147749
19 0.0019096402360084949
```

At this point, however, I'm stuck. The values in the transformed series are not particularly friendly and I don't see an obvious way to bound the partial sums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function is of the form $
_2 F_1(a,b;b-1;z) 
$. We can cancel $(b)_n / (b-1)_n = \frac{n}{b-1}-1$, and then note that
$
_2 F_1 (a,b;b;z) = (1+z)^a
$. After cancellation, the general case is
$$
_2 F_1(a,b;b-1;z) =\frac{ (a-b+1)z+(b-1)}{(b - 1) (1-z)^{a+1}}
$$In particular, your function is $\displaystyle{\frac{z+2}{2(1-z)^{1/20}}}$, which evaluates to zero at $z=-2$.

Comment: (+1) or using the third formula at Wolfram functions [07.23.03.0081.01](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/) ($(z-1)$ should simplify)

Answer (score 2):

By looking at what Maple does for this, I came up with the following.

Let $$F(k) = -3\,{\frac { \left( 2/3 \right) ^{k}k}{k! }
\Gamma \left( {\frac{19}{60}}+k \right) }$$

Then
$$ F(k+1) - F(k) ={\frac {(2/3)^k \left( -19/30+k \right) }{k!}\Gamma \left( {\frac{19}{60}}+k \right) }
$$

Now after some simplification

$$ {}_2F_1(11/30, 19/60; -19/30; 2/3) = 
- \frac{30 \Gamma(41/60)}{19 \pi \csc(19\pi/60)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(19/60+k) (-19/30+k)(2/3)^k}{k!}$$

so that
$${}_2F_1(11/30, 19/60; -19/30; 2/3) = const \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty (F(k+1) - F(k)) = const \cdot \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} F(k) - F(0)\right) = 0 $$

Comment: To be clear, we have $F(k)\to 0$ by Gautschi's inequality, which gives $\Gamma(19/60 +k)/\Gamma(1+k) < k^{19/60-1}$, and so $|F(k)| < 3 (2/3)^k k ^{19/60}$.